# Does "Hello World!" program compiled by JDK 7u3 runs with an older JREs (eg. JRE 6)?

Tags: java

Does `Hello World!` program compiled by JDK 7u3 runs with an older JREs (eg. JRE 6)?

If the answer is `YES`, When a java program doesn't run with an older JRE?

Comment: I can't work out what the second question is asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default the class files produced by javac will have a version number appropriate for the JDK they were produced on. To produce class files for earlier versions you will need to specify `-target` and to do that you will also need `-source`. `-source 1.6 -target 1.6` say.

However, you will still be picking up the current Java library, which contain classes, methods (possibly overloads), etc., that were not in the previous version. To sort that out, use `-bootclasspath` to point to the `rt.jar` of the target JRE.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. You will get classloader exception complaining about non supported class version. Unless of course you specifically target lower version when compiling